# Using vb6 application in Oracle 12c database

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, dll, com, vb6-migration

I have an vb6 application working using Oracle 10g which uses oo4o to connect with database. From the recent version (Oracle 12c) has stopped supporting oo4o. So I am trying to write a .dll file in C#, so that oracle 12c can be connected. So is it possible to write a .dll in c# which will connect to vb6?

Please do me give some reference to accomplish this task.

Thanks,

Comment: Of course, it´s possible to create a DLL using C# that can be used together with VB6/COM applications... anyway, what you´re trying to achieve feels wrong and will probably result in a dirty/hacky solution. I would consider using another way to connect, or just implement new functionality entirely in .NET and invoke that from your VB6 codebase.

Comment: yes, I had the same thing in my mind.Long story short: If I migrate the entire connectivity then I have to make some changes in vb6 source code. I know it is kind of wired but I'm not allowed to change anything in the Original vb6 code. Can you please help me in accomplishing this task? Can you give me some references to read ?? Thanks for your reply man :)

Comment: Consider a technical upgrade instead... convince your boss. It´s overdue.